# Not able to authenticate a service account with Google API PHP Client

Tags: google-api-php-client, service-accounts, google-indexing-api

I am new to this so I took cue from various official documentations to create a service account etc and use PHP client for Google API to make HTTP requests by using the credentials JSON for that service account.

But I am not sure what's going wrong, it just doesn't work ( for context I am trying to use the Indexing API - https://developers.google.com/search/apis/indexing-api/v3/prereqs#php )

```
require_once ABSPATH . '/googlelibraries/google-api-php-client/vendor/autoload.php';

$client = new Google_Client();
$serviceKeyFile = __DIR__ . '/daxxxxx-b1xxxxxxc8.json';
$client->setAuthConfig( $serviceKeyFile );
$client->useApplicationDefaultCredentials();

$client->setSubject( 'ixxxxxxxxn@gmail.com' );
$client->addScope('https://www.googleapis.com/auth/indexing');
$client->setAccessType('offline');
// $client->createApplicationDefaultCredentials();
// $client->setClientId( '10xxxxxxxxxxx' );
$endpoint = 'https://indexing.googleapis.com/v3/urlNotifications:publish';
```

This is what I have, almost the same as the one on the example documentation, however, when I call `$client->authorize()` to get a Guzzle client authenticated to make request I see nothing, everything just becomes blank, no error, I was able to debug it later and the error goes like -

```
Fatal error: Uncaught Exception: Magic request methods require a URI and optional options array
in /var/www/html/googlelibraries/google-api-php-client/vendor/guzzlehttp/guzzle/src/Client.php on line 84
```

I do not care if it authenticates or not, the problem right now is that `authorize` method itself it throwing an error and I don't know exactly what it is, there's no detailed guide on it that I would find. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not all google apis support service account authentication.  You appear to be trying to use the indexing api. If you check the documentation [#OAuth2Authorizing](https://developers.google.com/search/apis/indexing-api/v3/authorizing#OAuth2Authorizing) You will find that it only mentions Oauth2 authorization this is because service account authorization is not supported by this api.

You will need to switch to Oauth2.

Comment: Thanks, my application was a server-to-server API calls, so I generated a refresh token using OAuth Playground by Google, then used that refresh token to make calls to the Google API to get an access token and finally used cURL HTTP requests in PHP to make the Indexing API calls, so it does my job. Thanks!

Comment: your refresh token will expire if you app is still in test just a heads-up